# Javascript regex equivalent to php failing

Tags: javascript, regex

Guess this is a pretty simple problem. I've got a regex and php that looks like this:

```
preg_match("#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=v\/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be/)[^&\n]+#", $v, $matches);
```

(It strips out the youtube-code from their different kind of urls). I have to port this to javascript, and I want to use the same regex-string.

I've tried the following:

```
yturl.match(/#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=v\/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be\/)[^&\n]+#/)
```

But this gives me this error in Firebug: `invalid quantifier`

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

(I have no experience with regex in Javascript. So please excuse my dumb question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several problems:

1. You've added the PHP delimiters (`#`) to your JavaScript regex.
2. JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind, so you can't use the PHP regex in JavaScript
3. Your regex is redundant. The third alternative matches everything the first one would match.
4. The regex has an error: `youtu.be` should be `youtu\.be`.

Try this instead:

```
var myregexp = /\b(?:v\/|v=|youtu\.be\/)([^&\n]+)/;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1];
} else {
    result = "";
}
```

This will yield exactly the same results as your PHP regex, but it's much easier to read. Whether it will return correct results is another question - the quality of the PHP regex leads me to suspect that it may have more problems than just the obvious ones.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that when researching. Ended up using `/^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/` instead. I hope it will work. Wanted to keep the existing regex because it worked so well in my php-script. Thanks anyways, case closed.

Answer (score 0):

You've still got the `#` delimiter in your regex from PHP...try removing that:

```
yturl.match(/(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=v\/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be\/)[^&\n]+/)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript regexp, you've used '/' as the delimiters, but you also added in the '#' delimiters from the PHP version.

remove the '#' symbols from the JS version

Answer (score 0):

PHP preg_match uses the Perl Style Regular Expression, where Javascript does not.  Take a quick read in at: http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2008/02/01/javascript-regular-expressions/ and let me know if that helps you understand the differences.